# How can get memory and CPU usage of hadoop yarn application?

Tags: hadoop, memory, mapreduce, cpu-usage, hadoop-yarn

I want to ask, after I've ran my hadoop mapreduce application, how can I get the total memory and CPU usage of that application. I've seen it on log and resource manager web page but I didn't get it.

Is it possible? Can I get it per job execution or on per application, and can I get it per node usage or total usage?

Thanks a lot....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can very well check the total memory and cpu usage of the application.

You may use the Job tracker UI, click on the counters link on the completed page, and might get a typical view as follows. The memory and cpu counters were highlighted.

[image]

Clicking on the highlighted links will show you the consumption by every Tasks (Map/Reduce) of the job.

To view these values of these consumption counters from command line, you may use

`hadoop job -counter <job-id> org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskCounter CPU_MILLISECONDS` for cpu usage

`hadoop job -counter <job-id> org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskCounter PHYSICAL_MEMORY_BYTES`  for memory usage

Comment: so this is per job, not for the whole jar that I executed?

Comment: yes, you have to manually count from all the jobs that ran using the jar that you have executed.

Comment: welcome.. One more thing, to count every task level (Map / Reduce) resource consumtion you have to click on the highlighted links.

Comment: oooooo, bro by the way can I ask you something again. I want to ask about memory and vcore configuration on yarn. The one that take effect on the job time performance is vcore right? not the memory configuration? Thanks2

Comment: I'm sorry I want to ask again, how can I see that on command prompt not on web view. Does hadoop save log like that web? thanks

Comment: yes, you can check in command line,  use `hadoop job -counter <job-id> org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskCounter CPU_MILLISECONDS` for cpu usage and  `hadoop job -counter <job-id> org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskCounter PHYSICAL_MEMORY_BYTES` for memory usage..